# Error starting or building dotnet project (nuget). Arch linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net, archlinux, nuget

Стоит задача доработки dotnet проекта. Рабочая ОС Linux Arch.

При попытке запуска любой из команд - dotnet run, build, restore.
подает на ошибке с сертификатом. Это на всех проектах даже только созданных.

Пример вывода с ошибкой.

```
Projects/DotNet/testAsp •NET v5.0.201  net5.0 on ☁️
>dotnet run    
Building...
/home/expai/Projects/DotNet/testAsp/testAsp.csproj : error NU3028: Package 'Microsoft.OpenApi 1.2.3' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain
/home/expai/Projects/DotNet/testAsp/testAsp.csproj : error NU3028: Package 'Microsoft.Extensions.ApiDescription.Server 3.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain
/home/expai/Projects/DotNet/testAsp/testAsp.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'Microsoft.OpenApi 1.2.3' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired.
/home/expai/Projects/DotNet/testAsp/testAsp.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'Microsoft.Extensions.ApiDescription.Server 3.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired.
/home/expai/Projects/DotNet/testAsp/testAsp.csproj : error NU3028: Package 'Microsoft.OpenApi 1.2.3' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain
/home/expai/Projects/DotNet/testAsp/testAsp.csproj : error NU3028: Package 'Microsoft.Extensions.ApiDescription.Server 3.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The repository countersignature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
```

Как исправить эту ошибку? Гугление не помогло, ест похожие проблемы но решение не помогает, может кто встречался данной проблемой на Arch?

Comment: У вас не хватает сертификатов в хранилище. При установке дотнета они должны были добавиться, но почему-то этого не произошло.

Comment: Както это можно решить? удаление и новая установка dotnet не помогает. На двух компах такаяже проблема везде ОС  Arch.

Comment: А может дотнет и не при чем, судя по ошибкам, они связаны с нугетом.

Comment: Сегодня устанавливал .Net 5.0 на Ubuntu 20.04 и все работает нормально, но это так просто факт к размышлению.

Comment: Плюсую вопрос. Столкнулся с той же проблемой. Тоже Arch Linux

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на вопрос кроется в
[этой статье на гитхабе](https://github.com/NuGet/Announcements/issues/49)

Если в кратце. У майков, как я понял, кончился срок действия сертификатов и поэтому на всех недебиановских дистрибутивах появляется сия проблема. Решения для пользователей дебиановских дистрибутивов описано в статье. Для остальных дистрибутивов решения пока нет.

UPD: На всякий случай посмотрел issues на гитхабе в NuGet. Вроде как, там нашли решение.

[Ссылка на обсуждение](https://github.com/NuGet/Announcements/issues/56)